# jQuery .each conflicts with jQuery select append

Tags: jquery, select, append

I'm simply adding options to a select tag (aka dropdown list).  Why doesn't the second loop work?  I will have to spend some time debugging jQuery, but if until I spend too much time, I figured I'd post this and move on to a new task.

**Here's my key/value pair array:**

var map = {
            "10": "ten",
            "11": "eleven",
            "12": "twelve"
        };

**This doesn't work:**

```
    jQuery.each(map, function(key, val) {
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(key).text(val)); 
    });
```

**This works:**

```
    for (key in map) {
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(key).text(map[key]));
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `jQuery.each` the `this` variable within the callback contains the current element, not whatever value it had in your outer scope.

Try this:

```
var that = this;
jQuery.each(map, function(key, val) {
    jQuery(that.Elements.DDLTest).append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(key).text(val)); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `this` in your first example has changed context; the `this` refers to the `map` reference, and since it doesnt have an `Elements` property, it fails.